# how to change the background of a div or table based of a text/script on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a harsh time to find a solution to my problem. 
In my web page I have a table that I want to change the background based on some text that will change inside the page automatically.

The text can be plain text or HTML, but that text/script or maybe CSS can be only at the END of the page (and only there) before closing body... like:

```
<"text that can be hidden for user but change the background">
</body></html>
```

that text that  automatically change 6 times on one day based on time (will be different text/html) must display a different background image that is somewhere else on the webpage.

In other words, I want to change **sunny.gif** or **cloudy.gif** background of a table based on a text/script found at the end of body.

Do you guys have some idea on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How you add those text? add css class to the element at the same time to change your style accordingly

Comment: that text/html come from a sensor who read some data, and can post some small text but I dont have too much memory to put the code in there.

Comment: The webpage is stored online and there I can pu how much do I need. Can you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest possible is to add a style with a CSS rule, like this, where the initial image is red and the *style* added at bottom of page change it to a yellow

```css
div, p {
  text-align: center;
}

.changeBkg { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray url(http://placehold.it/200/f00) center center / cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div class="changeBkg"></div>
<p> Some text bla bla bla</p>
<p> Some text bla bla bla</p>
<p> Some text bla bla bla</p>
<p> Some text bla bla bla</p>


<!-- text/style that change i.e. a background image -->
<style> .changeBkg { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200/ff0); } </style>

</body>
```